# Work along a Circle Arc Path

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Consider a mass with weight W and force F acting on the horizontal direction going through an arc of a frictionless circular path of radius r and angle $\theta$. Does that mean that the work done by the horizontal force F, assuming a datum on the beginning of the arc curve, is:
$$\int_0^{\frac{2\pi{r}\theta}{360}}{Fcos\theta{ds}}$$

[image]

Here is a drawing I made about it.

I have been researching on work by variable forces for a while now, but I can't seem to find a definitive answer to this query. Is my understanding correct? And is there a better way to express this? Thank you.

Comment: What is this $s$ quantity you are referring to?

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't specify. That's the position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your force is applied to a rigid body on a fixed axle, then the weight is supported by the axle, and your integral for the work done by a horizontal force is correct, with ds = r dθ (angles in radians), and a limit not expressed in terms of the variable.  If not on a fixed axle, things get more complicated.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's actually a rigid body, I think it's more like a particle that moves along the surface of an arc slope of radius r and angle $\theta$. So I'm assuming that the work done by the horizontal force decreases as it goes along the path, since the tangential component only does work. Does that same equation apply for that?

Comment: The calculation for the work done by the horizontal force would be the same.  The object would accelerate up the slope until the tangential component of the horizontal force was matched by the tangential component of gravity. Then it would decelerate (and oscillate).